# jQuery popup is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have this jQuery popup that does not display for some reason, it works in other places but not here, what am i doing wrong?

ASPX:

```
 <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ToolTip="TRNSLTAdd" CommandName="addContactBtn" ID="btnSubmitOperator" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="return PopupOpen(this)">
                            <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Add-22x22.png" ID="AddContact" runat="server" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <div id="modalSubmit" class="modal">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <p><%# Eval("FirstName") %> <%# Eval("LastName") %></p>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlNode" />
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTranslator" />
                                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="btnCancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonNo" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Cancel-22x22.png" ID="SaveContact" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton CommandName="btnSave" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="ButtonYes" runat="server">
                                    <asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Check-22x22.png" ID="SaveOperator" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

jQuery:

```
function PopupOpen($this) {
    if ($($this).attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        return false;
    }
    var modul = $($this).parent().find("#modalSubmit");
    modul.show();
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target === modul) {
            modul.hide();
        }
    };

    return false;
}
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    width: 20%;
    height: 12.5%;
}
```

If you need more code, let me know because as i said, i have implemented this in other places and it works, but with a different function name but still same

Comment: as you said it is working properly else where,  are you doing the same  thing "module.show()" ? every where. for jQuery modal, you have to call it using $.dialog... are you sure you did it correctly?.. refer https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: Do you have any errors either on server-side or in your browser console?